# many to many mapping in entity framework code first

Tags: linq, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I'm using Entity Framework 4 CTP5 Code First and I have a model along the lines of:

```
public class User {
   public int UserId { get; set; }
   public string Email { get; set; }
   public ICollection<Customer> TaggedCustomers { get; set; }
}
public class Customer {
  public int CustomerId { get; set; }
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  public string LastName { get; set; }
  public ICollection<User> TaggedBy { get; set; }
}
```

There is a many to many relationship where a User can 'tag' a Customer and a Customer can be 'tagged' by many users.  I have a working DbContext and I can query customers using

```
 var customers = DbContext.Customers.Include(c => c.TaggedBy);
```

But each customer will have all users that have tagged the customer.  How do I restrict the TaggedBy collection to just result with a specifed UserId?

I've tried along the lines of `DbContext.Customers.Include(c => c.TaggedBy.Select(x => x.Id == userId));` but that throws an error.

Comment: The title should represent the problem informatively.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[EF Feature CTP5: Fluent API Samples - ADO.NET team blog - Site Home - MSDN Blogs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2010/12/14/ef-feature-ctp5-fluent-api-samples.aspx)

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Product>() 
    .HasMany(p => p.Tags)
    .WithMany(t => t.Products)
    .Map(m =>
        {
            m.MapLeftKey(p => p.ProductId, "CustomFkToProductId");
            m.MapRightKey(t => t.TagId, "CustomFkToTagId");
        });
```

[Code First Mapping Changes in CTP5 - ADO.NET team blog - Site Home - MSDN Blogs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2010/12/10/code-first-mapping-changes-in-ctp5.aspx)

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
    .HasMany(p => p.SoldAt)
    .WithMany(s => s.Products)
    .Map(mc => {
        mc.ToTable("ProductsAtStores");
        mc.MapLeftKey(p => p.Id, "ProductId");
        mc.MapRightKey(s => s.Id, "StoreId");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Mark your collections as virtual and then you can easily do:

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Customer> TaggedCustomers { get; set; }
}

public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> TaggedBy { get; set; }
}

using(var context = new MyDbContext())
{
    var user = context.Users.Single(o => o.UserId == 0);
    var customers = user.TaggedCustomers;
}
```

Results in much cleaner code in my opinion.